# issues with UV unwraping

Tags: uv

When I'm trying to unwrap the mug, it becomes a circle, and not a rectangular map[image: Results of unwraping]

Comment: You need to add at least one vertical Seam to let blender unwrapp that part as rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

When unwrapping a mesh, we need to cut the mesh up, so that we could lay it out flat, with minimal stretching. However, Blender needs to be told where to make the cuts. These are called seems. Currently, you don't have any seams, so the mug just get crushed into the circle, with lots of stretching, as shown here.

[image: No seams]

To fix this, I would add a seam down one edge, as well as another one separating the bottom of the mug from the sides. This will result in a more rectangular UV map, like you want. (seams can be added, by selecting an edge, pressing "CTRL+E" then select 'Mark-Seam'. These are then marked as a red line.)

[image: Fixed UVs]

Depending on how you want to texture the mug, you may want to reshape the UV map into a perfect rectangle, either manually, or using an addon like
[UV squares](https://youtu.be/JN1lLYsdeWc)

I hope that this has been helpful